# Could not load type 'site._Default'

Tags: asp.net, web

I have develop a simple website using VS8 and C# when I debug everything works fine, then I built using Ctrl + Shift + B and when I upload the site to a godaddy server it display the next error:

---

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'testDemo._Default'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="testDemo._Default"%>
Line 2:
Line 3:

---

A solution I found is removing the part `Inherits="testDemo._Default"`, but when debuging it does not execute the "`Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`".

Does anyone knows what is causing this error?

Answer (score 39):

Simply change "CodeBehind" to "CodeFile" on your Line1

Comment: @gerardo-abdo can you accept the answer if it has solved your problem?

Comment: Great Solution Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In IIS right click on your website and select "Convert to Application" it may solve your problem.
I had same problem with virtual directory under my main website

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you uploaded the compiled .dll files in the /bin folder for the site?

Answer (score 0):

What the class name for your designer file? Does it match "_default" and is it in the namespace "testDemo"?

Comment: I believe this solve both questions:

namespace testDemo
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: I found the problem! As I´m using a subfolder called "testDemo/" on the server I had to add the /bin at root/bin/testDemo.dll

Comment: Yes! this was the problem i was facing for too long, thanks for the comment!