# Parser error 'Could not load type'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting a parser error when I try to access this page 
http://mosab2a.elkedeseen.org/reyady/

 
[image: Parser Error]

but locally it's working well

Answer (score 0):

Check the version in the web server vs the one you build against

Answer (score 0):

Try Re-Publishing your Site again correctly. Make sure to Re-build your site before publishing it. Follow all the steps correctly that are used to publish a site. Make sure you have the required .Net Framework installed in your server machine. Also try changing "CodeBehind" to "CodeFile" on your Line1 
Check this link ([Could not load type 'site._Default'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394003/could-not-load-type-site-default)) as well