# CodeBehind stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Using VS2008

I've been working with this (legacy) application for a year now, then last Friday, when trying to debug it, I get this error:

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to 
service this request. Please review the following specific parse error
details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'FIPS._Default'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FIPS._Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I underdstand I could simply change "CodeBehind" to "CodeFile", I've read [Could not load type 'site._Default'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394003/could-not-load-type-site-default), [CodeFile vs CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind) and [@ Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a(v=vs.90).aspx)

The problem is that we do use TSF and I am the only one with this situation, Why would I have to modify the whole project?

Please help me figure this out. What could have caused this error? How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/Admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FIPS.Web.Admin.Default" Title="FIPS" %>
```

That is supposed to be the guilty line, but the issue might not even be there; this project was working fine one day and then the next, kaputz! No changes have been applied to the code or computer, **BUT** automated updates out of my control might have been applied.

Comment: Please share your code behind as well. The exception essentially means that in dll into which is your page/web project compiled is no such type. This can be a simple error like you haven't compiled your web project before going to the page.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/Admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FIPS.Web.Admin.Default" Title="FIPS" %>

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not yet acquainted here

Comment: This is not codebehind. Codebehind is content of Default.aspx.cs :)

Comment: I'm having issued with my .net/vs or whatever installation. I ended up changing it to CodeFile and it would compile a couple of times after which I would have to change it back to CodeBehind. This continued back and forth for a while but eventually my installation started to crumble. I can only guess some Microsoft Magic was involved here. I hope I can break that spell by starting with a clean setup.